# Pass one extra parameter along with HttpPostedFileBase for Single File Upload

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my MVC application I have a View containing 
1. One drop down list
2. One File Upload 
3. One button for submitting the form.

**form code (View)**

```
<form id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="@Url.Action("ExcelUpload", "NBL")" method="POST">


  @Html.DropDownList("CustomerName", new List<SelectListItem>
  {
      new SelectListItem() {Text = "Customer 1", Value="CM1"},
      new SelectListItem() {Text = "Customer 2", Value="CM2"}
  }, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:auto" })


  <input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" size="23" style="margin-top:5px"/>

  <button class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button> 

</form>
```

I am able to pass my File in Controller successfully when I click the button.

**Controller code**

```
public ActionResult ExcelUpload(HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload)
{
    if (FileUpload != null)
    {
         // Do Stuff here.
    }
}
```

My Problem is I also want the drop down selected value in the controller when I click the button. How can I pass both the Drop down Selected value and the file together in the controller?

Comment: Change to: `ExcelUpload(HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload, string customerName)`

Comment: It Worked! Please post this as Answer so that I can mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the dropdown element is `CustomerName` and it's within the form. The browser will post it to the server as a key-value pair with the key being the name of the dropdown and the value will be the value the user has selected.

The MVC framework's default binder will look for an action named `ExcelUpload` that either has a parameter `string customerName` or the action has a complex type (`Model`) that has `CustomerName` as the property.

Change your action to:

```
ExcelUpload(HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload, string customerName)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your model as it is does not represent the view or data you want to use. So make a model like so:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Models
{
    public class MyUploadModel
    {
        [Required]
        public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
        [Required] 
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Use that model in your views to generate the form and then in controller:

```
public ActionResult ExcelUpload(Models.MyUploadModel myModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // all good, save                
    }

    return View(myModel);
}
```

Of course you could just add a string-parameter to your action, but this is much more robust and represents the MVC-pattern (Model/View/Controller).